# Material CDK Overlay flexibleConnectedTo doesn't accept Angular component as origin

Tags: angular, angular-material, overlay, angular-cdk

I have an Angular component, which is actually a button under the hood :

```
<app-button (click)="showText(thebutton)" #thebutton>
    <button type="button" class=""><span>Popover</span></button>
</app-button>
```

showText() method calls the PopoverService.open() method, which should display a popover (tooltip) next to the button.

Problem is, the popover appears on the upper-left corner of the browser window and not next to the  element.

```
<div id="cdk-overlay-0" class="cdk-overlay-pane" style="pointer-events: auto;">
    <app-popover>
        <div class="popover"></div>
    </app-popover>
</div>
```

app-button has a "display: inline-block; position: relative;" style, just like an ordinary html button.

When I change the code to an ordinary HTML button, it works as expected :

```
<button (click)="showText(thebutton)" #thebutton>Popover</button>
```

and Material CDK adds a "top" and "left" style as seen below:

```
<div id="cdk-overlay-2" class="cdk-overlay-pane" style="pointer-events: auto; top: 87px; left: 389.656px;">
    <app-popover>
        <div class="popover"></div>
    </app-popover>
</div>
```

A simple div with style "display: inline-block" works as well.

Why wouldn't an Angular component (with style "display: inline-block; position: relative;") not work and how can I make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it by adding ".elementRef" to the component :

```
<app-button (click)="showText(thebutton.elementRef)" #thebutton>
    <button type="button" class=""><span>Popover</span></button>
</app-button>
```

From the Angular Material CDK source code [here](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/cdk/overlay/position/flexible-connected-position-strategy.ts)

```
/** Possible values that can be set as the origin of a FlexibleConnectedPositionStrategy. */
export type FlexibleConnectedPositionStrategyOrigin = ElementRef | HTMLElement | Point & {
  width?: number;
  height?: number;
};
```

So the parameter 'origin' passed to the Angular CDK Overlay service has to be of type "ElementRef | HTMLElement" (or Point, which is { readonly x: number; readonly y: number; }).

I leave this here, hope this helps someone in future.

Comment: Great - thanks for following up with an answer. The API docs seem to have been updated, but it I didn't spot it until I found your answer https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/api#type_aliases